# Trying to make pvgrub: xen-setup-stubdom not found

Tags: xen

I wish to use pvgrub.

I'm using debian wheezy x86_64.

I did an apt-get soruce xen and apt-get build-dep xen, cd-ed into the xen source dir and issued "make world".

The package doesn't compile, it emits the error message:

```
...
/bin/sh: 4: ./xen-setup-stubdom: not found
make[2]: *** [ioemu] Error 127
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/install/xen-4.1.3/stubdom'
make[1]: *** [install-stubdom] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/install/xen-4.1.3'
make: *** [world] Error 2
```

Does anyone know what might be wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Finally I managed the vanilla xen 4.3.1 package to get compiled. I went smoothly, I did not do any magic, just downloaded it, and made world. However the Debian source package still won't compile, so it must be a Debian peculiarity.

Answer (score 1):

This was driving me nuts too. Here's the answer:

```
cd xen-4.1.4
CONFIG_QEMU=/root/xen-4.1.4/qemu
export CONFIG_QEMU
make stubdom
```